# What are the different methods of evaluating a postfix expression?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

As of now, the only method I know for evaluating postfix expression is using a *stack*.

The following question was asked in a past semester:

> What are the two different methods of evaluating a postfix expression?

I skimmed through online references but couldn't get any answer. Your answer could be of great help!

Comment: read up on expression trees and parsing.

Comment: I'm not sure this question has a real answer outside the context of this particular exam situation.